# Is it possible to save data somewhere other than in the node when using web3.js?

Tags: web3js, accounts

Is it possible to use the web3.js apis with geth and store the sensitive data elsewhere and specifically not save any data on the node?

I know I can save the sensitive data by looking at the docs, however I'm unsure if I can prevent the node from storing any data in it's database. I'm fine with it being in memory for the purpose of executing the request I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

web3.js is just another library (in the context of a JS application) which enables interacting with Ethereum network. So your Dapp (app which uses the web3js) could do any other task independent to web3.js. 
In other words, you write a JS app with whatever the functionality and include web3.js to interact with Ethereum network is a total possibility.